# How to make a Game Tree in R

Tags: r, list, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to write a program that plays checker and so far I am able to calculate the game tree of every possible move but only for two levels. To make the game tree I use a list and it gives this result for the first move :

```
a[[1]]
[[1]]
[1]  0 14 -9

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0 3 9

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  0 19 -7

[[2]][[3]]
[1]  0 19  9

[[2]][[4]]
[1]  0 35 -7

[[2]][[5]]
[1]  0 35  9

[[2]][[6]]
[1]  0 51 -7

[[2]][[7]]
[1]  0 51  9
```

So for every move you get the score, the location of the pawn moving and the move on the board. The problem is that I am not able to calculate the other moves because navigating in the list becomes hard using my function. So I am wondering, what is the easiest way to make a game tree with at least 5 levels in R ? Is it list or should I use another type of variable ?

Thank you!

Comment: With a good representation, the depth of the tree shouldn't matter. There is no reason to hard-wire in the depth. Base R doesn't make it very convenient to create your own recursive data structures (although it is certainly possible). You might want to look into the [data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) package.